Show that pdf of binomial distribution decreases when scaling $n$ and $k$
Let $f(k,n,p)$ be the pdf of a binomial distribution with $n$ trials with success probability $k$ each. I want to show the following for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$:
$$f(k,n,k/n) \geq f(xk,xn,k/n)$$
The intuition would be that when $p=k/n$ the most likely outcome is $k$ successes out of $n$ trials, but hitting this maximum likelihood exactly becomes more and more unlikely the more trials you do.

I have tried some approaches.
My first was to directly show that $$\frac{f(k,n,k/n)}{f(xk,xn,k/n)}\geq 1,$$
however I ran into a dead end here since the choose function in the pdf actually grows with $x$ but the rest (i.e. $p^{xk}(1-p)^{x(n-k)}$) decreases and I could not see a way to show that the  latter decreases faster than the former grows. Apart from showing this statement directly I also tried to come up with a proof by induction but I could not find a way to make the induction step work, mostly because I found it hard to simplify the combinatorial terms in a useful way.
I also tried an analytical approach investigating whether $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(xk,xn,k/n)$ is always positive for $x\geq 1$, however here the partial derivative looked like a nightmare.
Lastly, I thought about argument via the standard deviation of the binomial distribution with pdf $f(xk,xn,k/n)$.
Since this is given by $\sqrt{xnp(1-p)}=\sqrt{xk(1-k/n)}$, the standard deviation grows with $x$ which should mean we expect more deviation from the most likelihood estimate with larger $x$. However, this is not sufficient as a standalone argument since it could also be that the probability of hitting the most likelihood point itself increases and the standard deviation is only increased due to more extreme outliers. But here I don't know whether there are any other properties that I could use to show the statement.

Did you try using the Stirling approximation for the binomial coefficients? Some of the terms might cancel making it easier to compare.
